# php foreach continue

Tags: php, foreach, continue

I am trying to skip to the next iteration of the loop if certain conditions are not met. The problem is that the loop is continuing regardless.

Where have I gone wrong?

Updated Code sample in response to first comment.

```
    foreach ($this->routes as $route => $path) {
        $continue = 0;

        ...

        // Continue if route and segment count do not match.
        if (count($route_segments) != $count) {
            $continue = 12;
            continue;
        }

        // Continue if no segment match is found.
        for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if ($route_segments[$i] != $segments[$i] && ! preg_match('/^\x24[0-9]+$/', $route_segments[$i])) {
                $continue = 34;
                continue;
            }
        }

        echo $continue; die(); // Prints out 34
```

Comment: You are overwriting `$continue`. It is entirely possible to enter that it gets set to 1, then 2 in your loop iterations.

Comment: Set `$continue = 0;` right after the `foreach`...  I'll bet you won't get `1` anymore.  A for 2, you'd need to tell it to continue up 2 levels, so `continue 2;`, otherwise it'll just go to the next iteration of the `for` loop...

Answer (score 124, accepted):

If you are trying to have your second `continue` apply to the `foreach` loop, you will have to change it from

```
continue;
```

to

```
continue 2;
```

This will instruct PHP to apply the `continue` statement to the second nested loop, which is the `foreach` loop.  Otherwise, it will only apply to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 24):

The second *continue* is in another loop. This one will only "restart" the inner loop. If you want to restart the outer loop, you need to give *continue* a hint how much loops it should go up

```
continue 2;
```

See [Manual](http://php.net/continue)

Answer (score 12):

You are calling `continue` in a `for` loop, so continue will be done for the `for` loop, not the `foreach` one. Use:

```
continue 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` within the `for` loop will skip within the `for` loop, not the `foreach` loop.